# Build a "group by attributes" with cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm developping a small application with jquery and cytoscape.js. I can do almost what I expect, however, I'm blocked for several days on this topic : I would like to render the graph similar to what I can do in Cytoscape with the layout "group by attribute". In Cytoscape, the rendering is with circles, but it could be other layout per group. I was unable to find examples and I tried unsucessfully with boundingBox or pan().

The group of nodes filtered is displayed with the right layout (eg: grid or circle, etc...) but centered on the middle. I have something like that:

var persons= cy.nodes().filter('[Type="Person"]').select();
cy.elements(":selected").layout({ name: 'circle', boundingBox:{x1:'300', y1:'4OO', h:'500', w:'500'}});

Is there an existing layout I didn't see?
How can I do?

I'm not a "poweful" javascrip developper :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the concentric layout: http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/concentric

Set `concentric` and `levelWidth` appropriately to group your nodes in concentric circles as desired.

Comment: Hello,I don't understand your recommendation.
I already use concentric layout but the result is really different from "group by" layout in Cytoscape and I didn't find how group nodes with concentric layout. Is there any example available ?

Comment: I tried several option like this unsuccesfully:
concentric: function(){ return this.data('FamilyName'); },
levelWidth: function( nodes ){ return 10; },