# Cytoscape-cise layout extension does not load on large graph

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

I am trying to use the `Cytoscape CiSE layout extension` to display my graph in clusters. It is quite large, approx. 50,000 nodes with directed edges between all nodes combinations.

The elements are exported from the Cytoscape desktop app as a `json` file. I am just trying to run the layout given the elements and a cluster function, but it just heats up my computer excessively and is continuously loading in the browser window.

I've tried running the layout on a small example graph which works, and I am not adding any extra styling or animations, just simply swapped out the nodes and edges with the larger graph. I can't imagine really what optimizations I could do, as I am purely trying to run the basic layout.

**Are there any known performance problems with the CiSE layout?**

Or

**are there any alternative layout extensions that would be good to try if I simply need an easy way to specify clusters and have them styled in circular groups?**

```
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById('cy'),
            elements: large_elements,
            style: [],
            layout: 'cise',
            clusters: function(node) {
                return 1; //just for simplicity, one cluster
            },
        });
```

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344455/performance-and-layouts-of-cytoscape-js) Stackoverflow Question, it may answer your question (cytoscape is not designed for that many nodes and thus you have to use the preset layout for example)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking into another option that would be similar to the [Group attributes layout](http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Navigation_and_Layout.html#group-attributes-layout) available via Cytoscape desktop. I could not find such a corresponding layout on the Cytoscape.js website. [Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798491/build-a-group-by-attributes-with-cytoscape-js) tried implementing a group attributes layout using the pre-defined `concentric` layout, but it looks like they weren't successful. Any suggestion of if this is possible?